# Assign value of VBA functions to cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to check that my VBA code is functioning properly. Is there a way to write the output of functions to cells so that I can see what values were calculated while the code ran? Looking through Google, it seems like this is not possible, or that it is very complicated.

Comment: You can use `Debug.Print yourFunction()` to print the returned value in the immediate window.  Or simply `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value = yourFunction()` to output it to A1 on Sheet1.

Comment: You can assign values to cells in VBA code.  What you're asking is a bit vague though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several different ways. Lets say "SOMETHING" represents your function or variable.

-You can use a debug print to have it show in the in the bottom window of the VBA editor.

```
Debug.Print SOMETHING
```

-You could use a message box to have it pop up.

```
msgbox SOMETHING
```

-You could place it in a cell on your active sheet.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = SOMETHING
```

Comment: Thank you! The ActiveSheet.Range().Value was exactly what I was looking for